# How to make laravel run automatically each time I open a new terminal?

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, composer-php

I came from windows to Ubuntu and tried to install laravel following link
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0
I ended with the installer 1.4.... I don't recall which one so I decided to use

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

I ended with the installer 4.1.1 but if I close the terminal and open it again and run `laravel` it does not find the command. I found the following command searching for a solution `PATH="~/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"`
I have to run this each time for the laravel command to work. Is there a permanent solution? I'm new to linux and I'm having so many issues and could not find a solution. I plan to update laravel but I cannot even get this running properly.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19062-01/sun.mgmt.ctr36/819-5418/gaznb/index.html

Comment: While this question is (borderline) on topic here, you will probably get much better answers over at https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: How is this related to Composer? What do you mean by "run automaiically each time"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can include `export PATH="~/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"` in your `~/.bashrc` file at the end and save it.

Then you can either run `source ~/.bashrc` or close and reopen the terminal.

All paths written in `~/.bashrc` will be read each time you open a terminal no need to set the path for each terminal session.

Comment: I tried to use ~/.bashrc adn I get access denied where do I find such folder? If I wanted to update Laravel would this change?

Comment: `~/.bashrc` is a file not a folder. Try listing the contents of your (user) home by `cd ~ && ls -la` then look for the `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` file it should have something like `-rw-r--r--@` in the file permissions (first column)

Comment: IF you don't have a `.bashrc` file in your home directory you can create one or if you are using oh-my-zsh then you must have a `.zshrc` file in your home directory or create one